# How to Set Baud Rate 2.000.000 Using DCB Structure

Tags: c++, serial-port, baud-rate

How can i set the baud rate to 2MBaud in C source code on Windows / Visual Studio 2010.

```
dcb.BaudRate = 2000000UL; //doesn't work.
```

Data sending at least works, tested using a serial port monitor. My microcontroller and it's ftdi chip is also working fine with 2mbaud using Bray's terminal.

Is there any possibility to find out the current settings of a com port?

Comment: Have you read though [the "How to Ask" guide here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)? (Helpful hint: nobody here can read your mind.)

Comment: That's not a standard baudrate, much too high for real hardware.  Small odds that a custom driver implements it.  If it does then it is typically a virtual serial port and the baudrate doesn't matter at all.  Not providing any details at all in the question prevents a decent answer, voting to close.

Comment: FTDI usb-serial converters can handle up to 3MBaud ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at GetCommState() and SetCommState() API's and the DCB struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
DCB dcb;
dcb.BaudRate = 2000000;
...
SetCommState(hFile, &dcb);
```

At least that's how I interpret "Assigns an actual baud rate or an index by specifying a CBR_ constant" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450503.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying this, but the microcontroller is not answering anything. It works with Terminal or Matlab serial ports and a Serial Port Monitor is telling me that the correct data was sent.

Btw, 2Mbaud are possible because of using FT232 usb-serial converter.

Comment: @Thomas: Are you sure your microcontroller's serial port is capable of working at such a speed? Also, do you need to take into account RTS/CTS/DTR/DSR?

Comment: @Alex: Yes I'm sure. Everything works when i use MATLAB serial classes or Brays Terminal

Comment: Is there any possibility to find out the current dcb settings of an opened port via some external software?

Comment: This is a new question. Try SystemInternals' ProcessMonitor.

Comment: OK, just to go over all that.  Using your app, the Serial Port Monitor is showing that the correct data was sent to the uC?  What is a 'Serial Port Monitor' - is it a separate hardware box?

Comment: I'm using this serial port monitor: http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/index.html

Comment: OK, so it's software and so doesn't mean much.  I would go with hardware here.  Send a stream of 0x55 or 0xAA, shove a storage scope on the tx pin and, (if the data is coming out at all), measure the bit width.

Comment: Also. please define 'doesn't work'.  Does the uC UART rxData interrupt or error interrupt fire at all?

Comment: My scope shows that the baudrate using my c++ is more than 100x slower than using the 2mbaud with the terminal app which is working very good.
I'm really sure that something doesn't work when i set dcb.Baudrate = 2000000

Comment: yea writing now works. problem was that the number 2.000.000 was set during initializing a global var, when i set it directly before setting dbc it works. thanks for your help!

Comment: ..and your problem has now moved - what was it that overwrote the global var and what is it overwriting now?  :)